# How to keep app's storage data persist even after uninstalling app in Android 10 (API 29)

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-storage

Since [`getExternalStorageDirectory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()) is deprecated on Android 10 (API 29), I'm using [`context.getExternalFilesDir()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) for storing downloaded files in internal storage by granting `Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, but as per documentation:

> This is like getFilesDir() in that these files will be deleted when the application is uninstalled

I am not targeting SAF, as I don't want to let user chooses the directory with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: "I don't want to let user chooses the directory with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE." -- if the file is a form of media, use `MediaStore`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you very much for this hint.. Yep some of them are mp3 files, and others are database (.db files).. If I may ask in this context, Does `deleted when the application is uninstalled` includes updating the app?

Comment: "Does deleted when the application is uninstalled includes updating the app?" -- no, just like your `SharedPreferences` and other persistent data, `getExternalFilesDir()` contents are retained on an app update. If the user uninstalls the app, the `getExternalFilesDir()` contents are deleted. Similarly, if the user does "clear data" in Settings for your app, `getExternalFilesDir()` contents are deleted.